# Something that can search and replace a hex string but for multiple files?

Tags: windows, find-and-replace, hex-editor

Hi I'm looking for a hex editor kind of thing but for multiple files? Can Windows Grep do this or does it only handle text strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volker Schatz' [bined](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021143534/http://www.volkerschatz.com/hardware/bined.html)

But Perl by itself can do this sort of thing

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\xD5\x37/12/g' *.dat subfolder\*.* otherfolder\foo*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notepad++'s *Find in Files* feature (which yes, can also replace).

Just make sure to enable the [extended](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#extended-search-mode) search mode and prefix `\x`.